# While uploading unmanged beta package i get unexpected error

Tags: unmanaged-package

While uploading unmanged beta package i get following unexpected error.

> error  Upload Failed An unexpected error occurred when uploading your
>   package. Please contact Salesforce Support and provide the following
>   error code: 1311478477-26097 (1548969588).

Before raise the case to salesforce support, is there any other option to resolve the issue manually ?
Please help me regarding this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here are couple of the ways you can try:

1) Try to install on new dev org.
2) If you have source code then try to deploy it and see what is the error